# Find row in MySQL Database with specific id used c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to search for specific ID.
For Example: I want to search for specific ID

Can Anyone Help me.

If I do this code in c#:

```
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, First_Name,Last_Name,M_I,Phone,Mobile,Fax,Email,BirthDay,Gender,RegDate,Job, Nationality,Adreess,Area,Area_Code,City,Country,Notes  FROM customers_table WHERE ID like '%" + search.Text + "%'";
            MySqlDataAdapter adap = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adap.Fill(ds);
            dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //throw;
            MessageBox.Show("Please complete correct the fields");
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Clone();
            }
        }
```

Then : The Results is to display all context id where contains the context from search.Text

Comment: Can you please show the relevant C# code and tell what is not working exactly?

Comment: here:cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customers_table WHERE ID like '%" + search.Text + "%'";

Comment: i want to display specific id , not id contains the context of my textbox .Understand what i want to do?

Comment: @ronaldocr7 Instead of adding code to comments, could you edit your question with the relevant information?

Comment: Do you know what the `like` and `%` keyword is doing? The reason I ask is Assuming your ID is an int or long you can't use the Like keyword. if you absolutely need that functionality, you will need to cast the `ID` into string and then use the `Like` keyword

Comment: yes i know ,  in my case find all id contains the specific context

Comment: How about use "OR" to combine it?

Comment: From the above requirement I'm with @AngusChung on this you should use the OR not the Like

Comment: i want to display specific id , not id contains the context of my textbox for example the user want to search and enter one number to find id .only this .Understand what i want to do?

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what could be contained in the Search.Text?

Comment: THE NUMBER ID (ID IS identity).

Comment: contains  specific number of some customer

Comment: ok so lets say you have a row in your table with the ID of 123456 you want the user to type 123456 to get that row or do you also want it to pop up if the user types 1234 or 456 or 345 or 123456. Is this what you mean?

Comment: WHERE (ID like '%1234%') or (ID like '%456%')?

Comment: no i want to display record of specific id. for example if type 987874.

Comment: @AngusChung, you can't do that for two reasons:
1) ID is int and you can't use the like unless you cast it
2) the like will catch that id without the need for the or

Comment: display: name :John, surname:FLISTONES , and ID:987874

Comment: i used MySQL database connect with c# , and i want to do search with id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to search for a specific ID you will need to simply remove the Like, replace it with `=` equal sign and remove both of the `%` ampersands. your command should look like below:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, First_Name,Last_Name,M_I,Phone,Mobile,Fax,Email,BirthDay,Gender,RegDate,Job, Nationality,Adreess,Area,Area_Code,City,Country,Notes  FROM customers_table WHERE ID = " + search.Text;
```

**UPDATE:**

I forgot to mention that for Int you don't need the single quotes either so the above command should work for you

Comment: No problem, next time, please try to include as much information as you possibly can on the question so we can get to the answer faster :) good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely use parameters in your query. The way you pas values in your query is creating a lot of potential issues both from security perspective and also from error handling.

Here is a good example of how to do it http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html